# No module named 'phonenumbers' but it's already installed

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I run:

```
pip3 install phonenumbers
```

```
Successfully installed phonenumber-8.13.14
or
Requirement already satisfied: phonenumbers in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (8.13.14)
```

When I run any .sh or .py file that includes a *phonenumber* module I get:
`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'
```

I am using Terminal on MAC but I also tried on windows and I get the same issue.

### Edit

This is the .py file I'm trying to run. You can find it here: https://github.com/Konstantinos-Papanagnou/PhoneInformationTracer

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from phonenumbers import carrier
from phonenumbers import timezone
import sys
from bannermagic import printBannerPadding, printMessage


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

class ParserData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.print_banner()
        parser = self.configureParser()
        args = parser.parse_args()
        self.verbosity = args.verbose
        
        if args.input:
            self.list = False
            self.phoneNumber = args.input
        else :
            if not args.list:
                #parser.echo()
                sys.stderr.write('You need to specify at least -i or -l option!\n\nRun PhoneInformationTracer.py -h for more help\n')
                exit()
            self.list = True
            self.phoneNumbers = args.list
        self.outputfile = args.output
        if args.country_code is not None:
            self.countryCode = args.country_code
        else :
            self.countryCode = '+30'
 

    def configureParser(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PhoneInformationTracer.py')
        parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='The Phone Number imput to Examine')
        parser.add_argument('-cc', '--country-code', help='The Country Code, Default=+30 (GR)')
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='increase output verbosity')
        parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='Specify a phone list to enumerate')
        parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Specify a file to export the data')
        return parser

    def print_banner(self):
        printBannerPadding('*')
        printMessage("Welcome to Phone Information Tracer")
        printMessage("By Konstantinos Pap")
        printBannerPadding('*')


def ExamineNumber(phoneNumber, countryCode, verbosity=False):
    if verbosity:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Examining: ', phoneNumber, f'{bcolors.ENDC}')
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Country Code set: ', countryCode, f'{bcolors.ENDC}')  
        print('\n\n')

    try:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Validating...{bcolors.ENDC}\n')
        meta = phonenumbers.parse(countryCode + phoneNumber, None)
        if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(meta):
            print(f'{bcolors.FAIL} Phone Number could not be Validated. Exiting... {bcolors.ENDC}')
            return "Invalid", "Invalid", "Invalid"
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}', meta, f'{bcolors.ENDC}\n\n')
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
        print(f'{bcolors.FAIL} Phone Number could not be Validated. Exiting... {bcolors.ENDC}')
        return 'Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Invalid'
    if verbosity:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Retrieving Country {bcolors.ENDC}')
    area = geocoder.description_for_number(meta, 'en')
    print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Area: ', area, f'{bcolors.ENDC}\n')

    if verbosity:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Attempting to get Carrier Informaion {bcolors.ENDC}')
    carrier_info = carrier.name_for_number(meta, 'en')
    if carrier_info is not None and not carrier_info == "":
        if verbosity:
            print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Success {bcolors.ENDC}')
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Carrier: ', carrier_info, f'{bcolors.ENDC}\n')
    else:
        carrier_info = 'Could Not Be Traced'
        print(f'{bcolors.FAIL}Carrier could not be Traced!{bcolors.ENDC}\n')
    
    if verbosity:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Attempting to get TimeZone Information {bcolors.ENDC}')
    
    timezone_info = timezone.time_zones_for_number(meta)
    if timezone_info is not None and not timezone_info == "":
        if verbosity:
            print(f'{bcolors.BOLD} Success {bcolors.ENDC}')
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Timezone: ', timezone_info, f'{bcolors.ENDC}\n')
    else:
        timezone_info = "Could Not Be Traced"
        print(f'{bcolors.FAIL}Timezone could not be Traced!{bcolors.ENDC}\n')

    return area, carrier_info, timezone_info


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ParserData()
    print (data.list)
    if not data.list:
        a, c, t = ExamineNumber(data.phoneNumber, data.countryCode, data.verbosity)
        if data.outputfile is not None:
           with open(data.outputfile, 'w') as f:
               f.write('Number\t\t: Area\t | Carrier\t | timezone\n')
               f.write(f'{data.phoneNumber}\t: {a}\t | {c}\t | {t}\n')
    else:
        if data.outputfile is None:
            sys.stderr.write('-l flag requires -o flag as well\n')
            exit()
        with open(data.outputfile, 'w') as of:
            of.write('Number\t\t: Area\t | Carrier\t | timezone\n')
            with open(data.phoneNumbers, 'r') as ifl:
                lines = ifl.read()
            lines = lines.split('\n')
            lines = lines[:-1]
            for line in lines:
                if '+' in line:
                    number = line[3:]
                    countryCode = line[:3]
                else:
                    number = line
                    countryCode = data.countryCode
                a, c, t = ExamineNumber(number, countryCode, data.verbosity) 
                if data.outputfile is not None:
                    of.write(f'{number}\t: {a}\t | {c}\t | {t}\n')

    if data.verbosity:
        print(f'{bcolors.BOLD}Information Trace Completed Successfully!{bcolors.ENDC}')
```

Comment: please include the code which you are trying to run so that we can see the import statement.

Comment: also run 'pip list' in terminal and see if the required module is actually installed.

Comment: I added the code and the source of the repository so you can have a look. The 'pip list' command did indeed show ' phonenumbers             8.13.14 '. So it is installed.

Comment: You surely must notice the inconsistency here.  You may have installed the `phonenumbers` pip package, but it has installed `phonenumber`.  That's what you need to import.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new at this. All the imports in the file above are 'phonenumbers' just like the module I installed. Can you explain where the 'phonenumber' module is?

Comment: You're right, the underlying C library is called "phonenumber".  That's what it's trying to tell us.  Are you running this from within an IDE, which has its own installation of Python?

Comment: I'm running it straight from Terminal. Should I replace "phoneNumber" with "phonenumbers"? I don't think that will work though cause he's using it as an argument for us to input the phone number to analyse. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a virtualenv to run your application? If you're using it, check if the site-packages from your venv are being displayed when you run `sys.path` in the terminal REPL. If it isn't being displayed, the solution I found when the same problem occurred with me at windows, is manually putting the site-packages path into `sys.path` before the start of your code. But if you're not running the code across a virtualenv, try doing it.

Perhaps there is a better solution for the windows path trouble in python, but it worked without a hitch for me.

Comment: Nice, with virtualenv the program runs. However within the program I always get 'False' and 'Validating...' but that's another issue.

Comment: Can you explain briefly why virtualenv would make it work? Why would building a virtual environment make the program recognise the module?

Comment: There are so many possible explanations for this. The most plausible is that pip is not installing the packages into the right global execution environment, that was created when python has been installed in your os. 

I know some causes of this: a) more than one python version installed; b) or the default python scripts directory is not set in the windows PATH. I didn't look more deeply into your execution environment, so it may be being caused by another reason.

As a rule, I had faced the same problem in windows every so often.